# after successfull redirect from authorize page of twitter login not able to get user detials using passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, passport.js

I am using passport.js for twitter social login. In my Web app after a successful login, it will populate the tweets accordingly and will reply to the tweets as per the loggedIn user credentials. Currently, I am able to successfully redirect after login, but not able to fetch the user details which passport gives after successful login i.e (username, email). As a result, I am not able to go further.

Below is the node server.js file.
Kindly help me with this issue.

```
server.js
const express = require('express');
const TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
const twitConfig = require('./config/auth').twitterAuth;
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Create a new Express application.
const app = express();
// require('./routes/')(app);
// Use application-level middleware for common functionality, including
// logging, parsing, and session handling.
app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));

//initialize passport strategy for twitter login.
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: twitConfig.consumer_key,
    consumerSecret: twitConfig.consumer_secret,
    callbackURL: twitConfig.callbackURL
}, (token, tokenSecret, profile, callback) => {
        console.log('arguments in passport.use>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', arguments);
        console.log('profile in twitterStrategy>>>>>>>>>>>>>', profile,callback);
        process.nextTick(() => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('err in passport TwitterStrategy>>>>>>>>>>>',err)
                return callback()
            } else {
                console.log('inside the else condition no error found>>>>>>>>>>',profile)
            }

        })
    return callback(null, profile);
}));

const twit = require('twit');
const T = new twit(twitConfig);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, callback) {
    console.log('arguments in serializeUser passport.use>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', arguments);
    callback(null, user);
})

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, callback) {
    console.log('arguments in deserializeUser passport.use>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', arguments);
    callback(null, obj);
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

//load the routes 
app.use(require('./routes/twitterApi'));
app.use(require('./routes/token'));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('user in />>>>>>>>>>>>>>', req);
    res.render('index', {user: req.user})
})


app.get('/twitter/login', passport.authenticate('twitter'), (req, res) => {
    console.log('consoe.log req>>>>>>>>>>>>>', req);
    console.log('res >>>>>>>>>>',res);
});

app.get('/twitter/return', passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/' }), function (req, res) {
    console.log('inside the return failure');
    res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/');
})

// listen for requests :)
const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 9000, () => {
    console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an async/await example of how to perform a database operation on the User, after authenticating with passport strategy.

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: twitConfig.consumer_key,
    consumerSecret: twitConfig.consumer_secret,
    callbackURL: twitConfig.callbackURL
}, async (token, tokenSecret, profile, callback) => {

try {
    // Perform some kind of db lookup/create with profile object
    const user = await User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: profile.email
        }
    })
    // now your user object will be passed to your callbackURL
    return callback(null, user) 
}
catch(error) {
    return callback(error, error.message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @elarcoiris  for quick response, but this is not working and i dont want to store it on db, i will simply grap the username and pass it to another twitter api to grab tha data on username basis.

Comment: @RAVIsingh the user object returned in the callback is what you can work with, as mentioned in my comment. It gets passed to whatever function is attached to your callbackURL route.

Comment: if i tried to execute the code the callback function for passport.use() it never  get invoked i have printed console but whenever i try to run it never print it. is that because i am not storing it in db ?

Comment: @RAVIsingh you haven't created a user object to pass to your callback function. Once you've done that, passport makes available req.user in your callback function and you can access user details by eg. req.user.email